# help with dired function i wrote..how to insert current file at point into buffer?

Tags: dired, shell

i have zero coding skills but somehow (mainly goggle) managed to write this script

```
(defun z/dired-shell-other-window-beets ()
  "Open a shell with dired path in a new window and issue beet import on file at point "
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (shell)))
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)
(insert (concat "beet import "  (dired-copy-filename-as-kill) ))

))
```

what im trying to do is issue a interactive shell command (beet import) on the current folder point is on in dired

i managed to get the beet import inserted to the new shell buffer thats opened but how do i follow that with the current dir name/path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are already two keybindings that do something similar which we'll talk about and then we'll talk about making you're own command. First of all you can use `dired-do-async-shell-command` which is bound to  <kbd>&</kbd>  in dired. This will prompt for a command and will execute the command on the name of the filename that is marked or under your point. So you press  <kbd>&</kbd>  and then type "beet import" this will run your command! In a similar vein there is also `dired-do-shell-command` which is bound to  <kbd>!</kbd>

The last option is if you will be calling this very very often you can write your own function modeled after `dired-do-async-shell-command` like this:

```
(defun dired-do-beet-import (&optional arg file-list)
  (interactive
   (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg)))
     (list
      current-prefix-arg
      files)))
  (dired-do-shell-command "beet import" arg file-list))
```

This version of the command opens a subshell to run the command in, it has less error checking and it only works for the file under the point and not for any files that are marked:

```
(defun dired-do-beet-import ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((command (concat "beet import " (format "%S" (dired-get-filename)))))
    (with-current-buffer (shell)
      (insert command)
      (comint-send-input))))
```

Comment: Thx so much Jules. the function above does work! yet i really need it to run in a shell since sometimes there is interaction needed with the beets command. is there anyway to open a `shell` window and see what the command is doing in addition to interacting with it (choose options) in the shell window?

Comment: I updated my answer with another version

Comment: thx so much again. this is pretty epic ;-) yet there is still a small issue i think is due to not escaping the paths. when i issue the command i get this error: ```$ beet import /home/zeltak/mreview/Bangles/1986 Different Light error: no such file or directory: /home/zeltak/mreview/Bangles/1986``` when i go and manually escape the path to ```$ beet import /home/zeltak/mreview/Bangles/1986\ Different\ Light/``` the command works! i assume there is a way to escape the path in eshell properly? also small annoyance by me can the eshell open in a new split window as my original script ;-)

Comment: Should be fixed! Cheers!